# disprove kernel function $k(x,y) = x_1y_1-x_2y_2$

Tags: self-study, svm

I am confused about how to disprove a kernel function like $k(x,y) = x_1y_1-x_2y_2$. The method mentioned in the book is to create a Kernel Matrix with all the data. But here I do not have any data. I tried to use counterexample but failed.

Could someone tell me how to disprove it? Or maybe any hint to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for the book you found the problem in?

Comment: What do you mean by "disprove"?

Comment: @Xi'an here I mean to prove it is not a valid kernel function if it is not.

Comment: @RCarnell it is a question in my machine learning exam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the counterexample below
$$
x=[2,\sqrt3]^T, y=[3,3]^T, a=[-1,1]^T
$$
With the entries,
$$
a^TKa<0
$$
can prove the kernel matrix is not positive semidefinite. Therefore k(x,y) is not a valid kernel.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Kernel is generalised scalar product. For any real vector $a$: $a \cdot a \ge 0$.